# NestJS: How to use ConfigModule values in another module?

Tags: javascript, nestjs

This is how my **app.module.ts** of my nestJS looks like:

```
  @Module({
    imports: [
      ConfigModule.forRoot({ envFilePath: root + '.env' }),
      GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
        driver: ApolloDriver,
        cors: {
          credentials: true,
          origin: process.env.ORIGIN // <--
        }
      })
    ],
    controllers: [AppController]
  })
```

As the GraphQLModule parameter object gets a bit more complex, I would like to refactor it to a config function.

```
export default () => ({
  driver: ApolloDriver,
  cors: {
    credentials: true,
    origin: process.env.ORIGIN // <--
  }
});

@Module({
    imports: [
      ConfigModule.forRoot({ envFilePath: root + '.env' }),
      GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>(graphQLConfig)
    ],
    controllers: [AppController]
})
```

But how do I get access to the process.env variables which I imported within the ConfigModule envFilePath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the asynchronous registration method: `forRootAsync`. Something like:

```js
  @Module({
    imports: [
      ConfigModule.forRoot({ envFilePath: root + '.env' }),
      GraphQLModule.forRootAsync<ApolloDriverConfig>({
        driver: ApolloDriver,
        inject: [ConfigService],
        useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => ({
          cors: {
            credentials: true,
            origin: config.get('ORIGIN')
          }
        })
      })
    ],
    controllers: [AppController]
  })
```

[More details in the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/quick-start#async-configuration)

Comment: What about if `root` in `ConfigModule.forRoot({ envFilePath: root + '.env' })` is also depending on a env var value?

Comment: Then that config value should be set either via a shell env variable like `NODE_ENV=production node dist/main` or you should call `config` from`dotenv` as the second line of `main`